# How to upload a PDF in firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, pdf, flutter, firebase-storage

I am new to flutter and firebase,I want to upload PDF into firebase using flutter please help me to solve this by providing some resources or links..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please share what you have tried if you want SO users to help you. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dependency https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker to upload any kind of file to database.

```
final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Database');
Future getPdfAndUpload()async{
  var rng = new Random();
  String randomName="";
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    print(rng.nextInt(100));
    randomName += rng.nextInt(100).toString();
  }
  File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.CUSTOM, fileExtension: 'pdf');
  String fileName = '${randomName}.pdf';
  print(fileName);
  print('${file.readAsBytesSync()}');
  savePdf(file.readAsBytesSync(), fileName);
}

Future savePdf(List<int> asset, String name) async {

  StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putData(asset);
  String url = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(url);
  documentFileUpload(url);
  return  url;
}
void documentFileUpload(String str) {

  var data = {
    "PDF": str,
  };
  mainReference.child("Documents").child('pdf').set(data).then((v) {
  });
}
```

By this you can upload file to firebase storage and insert the url to realtime database.

Comment: what about if I need 2 extensions?

Comment: specify fileExtension

Comment: but how can I specify more than one extension at once?

Comment: you can't specify both at the same time, you have to pick two time if you want to pick two different type of files.

Comment: that's not optimal at all